# User Control button not firing from webform page

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, user-controls, updatepanel

I have created a user control for visitor to subscription of newsletter.

UserControl is withing the update-panel and is added to the main master-page.

Problem with the control is that Subscribe button is not firing for some reason

User control markup:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>    
    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="PrayerTimeWrapper">
        <tr>
            <td align="center">
                <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="PrayerTimeInnerWrapper" border="0">
                    <tr>
                        <td valign="top">
                            <div class="dHeading"><asp:Label ID="lblTitle" runat="server" Text="JOIN US"></asp:Label></div>
                            <div class="dName">
                                <asp:TextBox ID="txtName" CssClass="txtSubscribe" runat="server" Text="NAME" onfocus="if(this.value=='NAME')this.value='';" onblur="if(this.value=='')this.value='NAME';"></asp:TextBox>
                            </div>
                            <div class="dEmail">
                                <asp:TextBox ID="txtEmail" CssClass="txtSubscribe" runat="server" Text="YOUR EMAIL" onfocus="if(this.value=='YOUR EMAIL')this.value='';" onblur="if(this.value=='')this.value='YOUR EMAIL';"></asp:TextBox>
                                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvEmailSub"  runat="server" ErrorMessage="*" 
                                    ControlToValidate="txtEmail" ValidationGroup="SubEmail" ></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                                <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="revEmailSub" runat="server" 
                                    ErrorMessage="*" ControlToValidate="txtEmail" ValidationExpression="\w+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*" 
                                    ValidationGroup="SubEmail" ></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
                            </div>
                            <div class="dSubmit">
                                <asp:Button ID="btnSubscribe" CssClass="btnSubscribe" runat="server" Text="Subscribe" onclick="btnSubscribe_Click" />
                            </div>   
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>    
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

User control code-behind:

```
protected void btnSubscribe_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.Write("Test");
}
```

Markup of the page which is using master-page:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="PrayerTiming.aspx.cs" Inherits="PrayerTiming" %>
<%@ Register Src="~/en/UserControls/ucSubscribe.ascx" TagName="Subscribe"  TagPrefix="uc"%>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent" Runat="Server">
</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" Runat="Server">
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" EnablePartialRendering="true" />    
    <div align="center" id="table"></div>    
    <uc:Subscribe id="ucSB" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional" />    
</asp:Content>
```

I am doing something wrong somewhere but i am not sure what. I would appreciate help on this.

Comment: Button event is not firing ... when i debug

Comment: Is the page posting to the server when you click the Subscribe button?

Comment: just for curiosity waht the website is for?

Comment: It is general website with few web forms & simple newsletter subscription .. Not much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `Resonse.Write` during an `asynch resquest` can altere the data used to update proprely the controls within the update panel.

so instead of `Response.Write("Test")` use a `Label.Text = "Test"`

Comment: I did the by replacing the response.write statement with a proper label control which worked well. Appreciate you help. Thanks

Comment: @KnowledgeSeeker, you said you debugged this, clearly you didn't since a trace routine answered to your problem. I wonder if it still works after you remove ValidationGroup="SubEmail".

Comment: @Adrian lftode, the moment you pointed out out about validation group i thought it was the only problem. To my surprise it was not working event after that finally i made some change to the code which made it work & one of the change was to remove response.write statement. It is still not clear to me why it didn't work when i tried the similar way as mentioned by "Anouar204". Anyway i appreciate every bodies help. I had even given your reply up vote even before my problem was resolved.

Comment: @Adrian, it wont work if i remove validation group ValidationGroup="SubEmail"

Answer (score 1):

Set the ValidationGroup for the btnSubscribe button also

```
<asp:Button ID="btnSubscribe" 
      CssClass="btnSubscribe" runat="server" 
      Text="Subscribe" 
      onclick="btnSubscribe_Click" 
       ValidationGroup="SubEmail" />
```

**UPDATE**

From what I've seen in the comments and in the other answers, the only reason why the button didn't post the content to the server is because it didn't subscribe to that validation group. The ValidationGroup is used to separate certain views (group of controls) in a page so they use their own validation. For example a forgot password section and a login section would have two different validation groups so when a certain button is clicked only its section is validated.

*I did this update, because I truly think that the accepted answer is more a debuging advice than an actually answer. A future SO reader might jump to use this guideline instead of seeing the problem.*

Comment: For  a moment i though i got it, Even after adding the validation group still nothing is happening. Button event is not firing

Comment: @KnowledgeSeeker, the problem with Response.Write is that, when an UpdatePanel is used, is not working as you see it in the normal way, the non-AJAX way. In the normal way you'll see the written text on the top of the page, before any other html code, but with AJAX it doesn't work like this. I don't know actually where it puts that written text with AJAX, you can see it with Fiddler.

Comment: @KnowledgeSeeker: The problem is that when someone uses `Resonse.Write` during an asynch resquest he altered the data used to update the controls state nothing to have with Validation http://siderite.blogspot.com/2007/02/aspnet-ajax-and-responsewrite-or.html

Answer (score 0):

Try puting `UpdatePanel` in `form` tag with `runat="server"`...

Comment: i am using master-page so i cant add form tag to user control